# SPINNER communication and result

Tags: java, android, spinner

First, sorry for my english. I'm French and I searched a lot but I can't find a solution. And I'm novice.

I would like to use 3 spinner together, one button and one TextView.

My problem is actually, I don't know how to communicate them together to give me a result on a TextView.

I explain to you want I would like (and you can look at my code below).

If user select "markOne" in SPINNER spin, only "modelOne1" and "modelOne2" will appear in SPINNER spin2, and only "colorOne1" and "colorOne2" will appear in SPINNER spin3.

In SPINNER spin 3, if he chooses "colorOne1": "RED" will appear in a TextView, after he press the btn_valid.

If he chooses "ColorOne2": "BLUE" will appear in a TextView, after he press the btn_valid.

**OTHERWISE**

If user select "markTwo" in SPINNER spin, only "modelTwo1" and "modelTwo2" will appear in SPINNER spin2, and only "colorTwo1" and "colorTwo2" will appear in SPINNER spin3.

In SPINNER spin 3, if he chooses "colorTwo1": "ORANGE" will appear in a TextView, after he press the btn_valid.

If he chooses "ColorTwo2": "PINK" will appear in a TextView, after he press the btn_valid.

I know it's specific and take your time to helping me to complete my code. I haven't found a working tutorial with 3 spinner, button, TextView and it's really hard when you are French !

Hope you help me.

Thank you very much.

**My class**

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

String[] mark = {"markOne","markTwo"};
String[] model = {"modelOne1","modelOne2","modelTwo1","modelTwo2"};
String[] color = {"colorOne1","colorOne2","colorTwo1" ,"colorTwo2"};
private Button btn_valid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mark);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, model);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, color);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin3.setAdapter(adapter3);
    spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
}}
```

Comment: this is named hierarchical spinner, see this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001047/having-multiple-spinners-in-android

Answer (score 1):

**hi friend i have try this code on my way i hop it will useful to you**

```
Spinner spn1,spn2,spn3;
TextView txtResult;
String spn_1_Selected_item;
Button btnResult;

String[] spinn_mark1 = {"SelectMode","markOne","markTwo"};
String[] spinn_mode2 = {"modelOne1","modelOne2","modelTwo1","modelTwo2"};
String[] spinn_color = {"colorOne1","colorOne2","colorTwo1" ,"colorTwo2"};

ArrayAdapter adapterSpinner_1,adapterSpinner_2,adapterSpinner_3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spn1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_con_1);
    spn2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_con_2);
    spn3= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_con_3);

    txtResult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    btnResult= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


    adapterSpinner_1=new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinn_mark1);
    spn1.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_1);
            spn1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    spn_1_Selected_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    if(spn_1_Selected_item.equals("SelectMode"))
                        txtResult.setText("");
                    if(spn_1_Selected_item.equals("markOne")){
                        String model1[]={spinn_mode2[0] , spinn_mode2[1]};
                        String color1[]={spinn_color[0],spinn_color[1]};

                        adapterSpinner_2=new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,model1);
                        spn2.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_2);

                        adapterSpinner_3=new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,color1);
                        spn3.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_3);
                        spn3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String colorSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                if(colorSelected.equals("colorOne1"))
                                    txtResult.setText("Red");
                                if(colorSelected.equals("colorOne2"))
                                    txtResult.setText("Blue");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    if(spn_1_Selected_item.equals("markTwo")){
                        String model1[]={spinn_mode2[2] , spinn_mode2[3]};
                        String color1[]={spinn_color[2],spinn_color[3]};

                        adapterSpinner_2=new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,model1);
                        spn2.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_2);

                        adapterSpinner_3=new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,color1);
                        spn3.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_3);


                        spn3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String colorSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                if(colorSelected.equals("colorTwo1"))
                                    txtResult.setText("Orange");
                                if(colorSelected.equals("colorTwo2"))
                                    txtResult.setText("Pink");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        }
```

}

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Spinner Control"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    style="@style/Platform.AppCompat.Light"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_con_1"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_con_2"
    />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_con_3"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    style="@style/Platform.AppCompat.Light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />
```

Comment: Hi DHruv. First, thank you very much. I think t's a good base but this code don't work for me. It seems something doing wrong. Maybe you forget something inside, I don't know. Code show me a color directly after I select a mark. It didn't wait I choose a model. I work on it and try to modify but my problem isn't resolved.